# CoffeeScript idiom to either call function or property getter

Tags: function, properties, coffeescript, shortcut

An objects property can be a simple property or a function. Is there some easier way in CoffeeScript to get the `value` of this property?

`value = if typeof obj.property is "function" then obj.property() else obj.property`

Comment: I think if you need this you're trying to make CoffeeScript into something that it isn't. Do you really want to wrap every single access of an object's method in a `if` statement? You should know whether you're accessing a property or invoking a method.

Comment: Its a common pattern. A named property can be a simple property or a more complex function. The reason for this question is exactly to prevent me from wrapping every such assignment in this awful code.

Comment: It's a common pattern in *other languages*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is idiomatic but you could use (abuse?) the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators-existential) for this purpose.

When you say this:

```
obj.p?()
# ---^
```

CoffeeScript will convert that to:

```
typeof obj.p === "function" ? obj.p() : void 0
```

so if `p` is a function, it will be called, otherwise you get `undefined`. Then you can toss in another existential operator to fall back to `obj.p` if `obj.p?()` is undefined:

```
obj.p?() ? obj.p
```

There is a whole in this though, if you have:

```
obj =
    u: -> undefined
```

then `obj.u?() ? obj.u` will give you the whole function back rather than the `undefined` that the function returns. If you have to face that possibility then I think you're stuck writing your own function:

```
prop = (x) ->
    # Argument handling and preserving `@` is left as an exercise
    if typeof x == 'function'
        x()
    else
        x
```

and saying `x = prop obj.maybe_function_maybe_not`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hyv6pdtc/

If you happen to have Underscore around, you could use it's [`result`](http://underscorejs.org/#result) function:

> **result** `_.result(object, property)`
>
> If the value of the named **property** is a function then invoke it with the **object** as context; otherwise, return it.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using underscore but WinJS. I can inject this functionality easily there too. I wonder if iced CS supports this out of the box.